# Common Lisp The Language 2 outdated?

Tags: struct, common-lisp

In CLTL2 there is a struct example `ice-cream-factory` as [follows](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node174.html#SECTION002360000000000000000), which would allegedly create two constructors. Here is the structure definition:

```
(defstruct (ice-cream-factory 
             (:constructor fabricate-factory 
               (&key (capacity 5) 
                  location 
                  (local-flavors 
                    (case location 
                      ((hawaii) '(pineapple macadamia guava)) 
                      ((massachusetts) '(lobster baked-bean)) 
                      ((california) '(ginger lotus avocado 
                                      bean-sprout garlic)) 
                      ((texas) '(jalapeno barbecue)))) 
                  (flavors (subseq (append local-flavors 
                                           '(vanilla 
                                             chocolate 
                                             strawberry 
                                             pistachio 
                                             maple-walnut 
                                             peppermint)) 
                                   0 capacity))))) 
  (capacity 3) 
  (flavors '(vanilla chocolate strawberry mango)))
```

CLTL2 states:

> The structure type ice-cream-factory has two constructors. The standard constructor, make-ice-cream-factory, takes two keyword arguments named :capacity and :flavors. For this constructor, the default for the capacity slot is 3 and the default list of flavors is America's favorite threesome and a dark horse (not a dead one).

However evaluating the standard constructor however runs into an undefined function error:

```
(make-ice-cream-factory)
```

> The function COMMON-LISP-USER::MAKE-ICE-CREAM-FACTORY is
>   undefined.

Is this because the part of the book doesn't correspond to the latest standard on `defstruct`s?
Specifying the `:constructor` option i am having only one constructor `fabricate-factory`.

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] the question to include the key information from the link? That saves everyone having to click through and find the relevant information, and makes sure the question will remain useful if the linked page changes or stops working in future.

Comment: CLtL2 is obsolete and cannot be used as a reliable reference. Please use [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one constructor. If it mentions two, then that's an error.

For details on standard Common Lisp, look at the ANSI CL standard and derived documentation like the [DEFSTRUCT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm#defstruct) entry in the HyperSpec:

> defstruct creates the default-named keyword constructor function only if no explicit :constructor options are specified, or if the :constructor option is specified without a name argument.

Since

```
(defstruct (ice-cream-factory 
            (:constructor fabricate-factory 
             (&key (capacity 5) 
                   location 
                   (local-flavors 
                    (case location 
                      ((hawaii) '(pineapple macadamia guava)) 
                      ((massachusetts) '(lobster baked-bean)) 
                      ((california) '(ginger lotus avocado 
                                             bean-sprout garlic)) 
                      ((texas) '(jalapeno barbecue)))) 
                   (flavors (subseq (append local-flavors 
                                            '(vanilla 
                                              chocolate 
                                              strawberry 
                                              pistachio 
                                              maple-walnut 
                                              peppermint)) 
                                    0 capacity))))) 
  (capacity 3) 
  (flavors '(vanilla chocolate strawberry mango)))
```

has a constructor named `fabricate-factory`, there will be no default name constructor created.

Comment: Thank you, my question was only if that is an inaccurate information in the CLTL2.

Answer (score 4):

CLtL2 not only is hopelessly obsolete, it never really specified CL at all.  *CLtL* specified a version of the language, while CLtL2 was just some snapshot of what was happening during the standardisation process.  This was widely-understood at the time, but seems to have been partly forgotten since.

That being said the section you are referring to is not an example of the book being obsolete: it's just a mistake in the book. Section 19.6, 'By-Position Constructor Functions' of CLtL2 starts with this text:

> If the `:constructor` option is given as `(:constructor name <arglist>)`, then instead of making a keyword-driven constructor function, `defstruct` defines a "positional" constructor function, taking arguments whose meaning is determined by the argument's position rather than by a keyword.

(I've replaced italics by `<angles>` above.)

But then the example you are looking at just gets this wrong.  Not only that it's internally-inconsistent: the text talks about a function `make-ice-cream-factory` but the example code contains `make-factory`.

A `defstruct` form which makes the code of the example be right would be

```
(defstruct (ice-cream-factory 
             (:constructor fabricate-factory 
               (&key (capacity 5) 
                  location 
                  (local-flavors 
                    (case location 
                      ((hawaii) '(pineapple macadamia guava)) 
                      ((massachusetts) '(lobster baked-bean)) 
                      ((california) '(ginger lotus avocado 
                                      bean-sprout garlic)) 
                      ((texas) '(jalapeno barbecue)))) 
                  (flavors (subseq (append local-flavors 
                                           '(vanilla 
                                             chocolate 
                                             strawberry 
                                             pistachio 
                                             maple-walnut 
                                             peppermint)) 
                                   0 capacity))))
             (:constructor make-factory))
  (capacity 3) 
  (flavors '(vanilla chocolate strawberry mango)))
```

while one which makes the text be right would be

```
(defstruct (ice-cream-factory 
             (:constructor fabricate-factory 
               (&key (capacity 5) 
                  location 
                  (local-flavors 
                    (case location 
                      ((hawaii) '(pineapple macadamia guava)) 
                      ((massachusetts) '(lobster baked-bean)) 
                      ((california) '(ginger lotus avocado 
                                      bean-sprout garlic)) 
                      ((texas) '(jalapeno barbecue)))) 
                  (flavors (subseq (append local-flavors 
                                           '(vanilla 
                                             chocolate 
                                             strawberry 
                                             pistachio 
                                             maple-walnut 
                                             peppermint)) 
                                   0 capacity))))
             (:constructor))
  (capacity 3) 
  (flavors '(vanilla chocolate strawberry mango)))
```

All of this works as specified in CltL2 in an an ANSI-conformant implementation.